# Semicircle Navigationmenu with html, css and js

Tags: html, css

i am trying to create a semicircle menu with animations and texts.
Currently i try to position the texts in the semicircle which is only working with a specific window-width and browser.

This is my current approach: https://codepen.io/Jxner/pen/xxGBKYJ

```css
.menu {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 150px auto;
  width: 70%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 70%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
  .menu {
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 700px) {
  .menu {
    width: 1080px;
    height: 1080px;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.menu li { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  clip-path: url(#sector);
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
<div id="wrapper">  
  <div id="left">
    <ul class="menu" id="navigation_menu">
      <li class="one edge">
        <span class="icon_one">One</span>
      <li/>

      <li class="one" id="cat1">
        <a href="#" onclick="clicked_cat1()">
        </a>
      </li> 
      <li class="two edge">
        <span class="icon_two">Two</span>
      </li>
      <li class="two" id="cat1">
        <a href="#" onclick="clicked_cat1()">

        </a>
      </li> 
      <li class="three edge">
        <span class="icon_three">Three</span>
      </li>
      <li class="three" id="cat1">
        <a href="#" onclick="clicked_cat1()">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

<svg height="0" width="0"> 
  <defs>
    <clipPath clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="sector">
      <path fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="1" class="sector" d="M0.5,0.5 l0.5,0 A0.5,0.5 0 0,0 0.75,.066987298 z"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

I am fairly new to css, so this seems like a really laborious way just to create a semicircle with 3 segments and an edge for each one.

How can i improve my code to better scale and run it in different browsers and how can i fix my text to the "pie-segments" so it doesn't disappear with different window sizes?